# Inner HTML issues in DOJO while creation select and options?

Tags: dojo

While creating select option in dojo

```
dojo.byId("it1").add(dojo.create("option", { value:'1',innerHTML:'Iteration 1' }));
```

I got a Invalid argument error in IE8, rest of the browsers works fine.

Comment: This might help: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Add-items-dynamically-to-select-box-td3421068.html

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?  What is the exact error message?  Can you share the rest of the context of the issue?  Can it be recreated in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to that browsers has implemented sort of a fail-over mechanism. Or maybe even the standards has changed, not sure which it is.
Fact remains, that in older browsers, the `option` element had an odd implementation. Consider the following programmatic creation of a new `option` DOM:

```
text='Iteration 1';
value=1;
defaultSelected = false;
selected=false;

document.getElementById('myselect').options.add(
  new Option(text, value, defaultSelected ,selected)
);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd757810(v=vs.85).aspx

The API also has arguments, indicating if option is selected or not. But the interesting part here is the parameter `text`

It roughly translates into

```
var opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
opt.text = text;
opt.value = value;
```

You will find, that programmatically created selects (using `innerHTML` approach) will not work properly in IE prior to and including IE8. The element is simply not connected to its parent form and thus, not sent to server on submit.